# Validation Form With Ajax in Asp.net Core

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I use AJAX to send forms to controller in ASP.NET Core but I have problem with send form with validation

```
<form asp-action="Create" asp-controller="Departments"
      data-ajax="true"
      data-ajax-method="Post"
      data-ajax-mode="replace"
      data-ajax-update="#content"                 
      data-ajax-success="Success"
      data-ajax-failure="Failure">
    <div class="box-body">
       <div class="alert alert-success" id="divalert" ></div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Title" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="ثبت" class="btn btn-success" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is Jquery code For Ajax

```js
<script>
    function Success() {
        $("#divalert").text = "Yes";
    }
    function Failure() {
        $("#divalert").text = "No";

    }

</script>
```

but I want to show validation message ehen I send form with empty text Box ,

This is my Controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Department_Id,Title,Task,Description,Department_Status")] Department department)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {             
        _genericRepository.Add(department);
        await _genericRepository.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    return View(department);
}
```

How do I show validation message with Ajax when form is empty ?

Comment: @mplungjan, OP is using the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` plugin (which makes an ajax call)

Comment: The code you have shown will work fine, and will not submit assuming you have a `[Required]` attribute on the `Title` property. Do you have all the relevant scripts loaded correctly?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Where can I see that?

Comment: @mahdi: PLEASE do not capitalise every word in your question. It is really irritating to read

Comment: i change IActionResult To Jsonresult it is true?@mplungjans 
@StephenMuecke

Comment: That has nothing to do with client side validation!

Comment: when model state is flase return json 
and show validation message .@StephenMuecke

Comment: If your form is submitting, then you have not loaded the relevant client side validation scripts

Comment: what to write ?
Please Write Sample Code For This Work.
@StephenMuecke

Comment: You need to include `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` in your view or layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use partial view "Create" and it works

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <form asp-action="Create" role="form" asp-controller="Department" asp-antiforgery="true"
          data-ajax-success="Bindgrid"
          data-ajax="true"
          data-ajax-method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" asp-for="DepartmentName"></label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" asp-for="DepartmentName" />
            <span asp-validation-for="DepartmentName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save" />
    </form>
</div>
```

all jquery file is needed for html or ajax validation.